# converting a string to float doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I got a variable Javascrpit which has a number as a string in this case 0.84. I'm trying to convert it into a float but when I try to it appears a 0 as float instead the 0.84.

I'm using this:

```
var pot="0.84";

var asd = parseFloat(pot);

console.log(asd);
```

EDIT:

This is not exactly the example. I recover data from the HTML and it works for other numbers but not for this. It is difficult to explain my problem exactly. It is a lot of code and works for other numbers so don't know exactly.

Comment: Works fine for me, prints 0.84 to the console.

Comment: @takendarkk, if you test with parseFloat("0. 84"), your result will be 0. I believe that's the problem here.

Comment: If you provide us a reproducible example we can know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not "0.84". If you test with that, you will get the correct answer. Your input has something else inside, like spaces, for example:

"0 .84"

This should be the solution:

```
parseFloat(pod.replace(/ /g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this example on my end and it completely worked. However, you can try to instead input the string value directly into the parse float() function and it should print our your expected value. If you still want to assign the parsefloat() to a variable, then try to either rewrite the code or re-open your IDE because the code should work.

```
var pot = "0.84"
console.log(parseFloat(pot))
```

or you can just write it in one line

```
console.log(parseFloat("0.84"))
```